# Treating a string as a list

Tags: python

A novice question here

I am dealing with lists of strings of different lengths (where each string is numeric) such as

```
a = ['1', '5', '8', '11']
```

I need to evaluate the last item in each list using: a[-1] which is fine most of the time.

However, when the list has just one item which is more than 1 character in length, i have an issue:

```
a = ['10']
```

Since i am using a For loop:

```
for el in a:
   el[-1].....
```

`el[-1]` is then equal to '0' and not '10' as i need it to be

How can i overcome this?

### Thanks

editing the post. 
Thanks folks for all the suggestions. I am sorry, but i made a complete mess of the question, did not state the problem correctly. 
I've got a list of lists, all of which look like a above:

```
mylist = [a, b, c, ....]     #a = ['1', '5', '8', '11']....
```

I am then executing a loop over mylist where the last element of each list points to dictionary key mygraph2.nodes[el[-1]]:

```
for el in mylist:
      for loop_var in mygraph2.nodes[el[-1]].neighbors:
             further code here....
```

I found a way around my issue, but it is not elegant.

```
if len(el) == 1:
    el = mylist
```

I forced the last element to be a list even the list 1 item long.
Thanks again

Comment: `a[-1:]` gives you a slice, instead of the object even if it's one element. Not sure of this is Python2 or Python3 specific tho.

Comment: Have you tried el[0]

Comment: What does `a[-1]` give you? - 10.

Comment: `for el in a` already gives you each individual element in `el`. There is no need to use any indexing at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right, it's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. it's ok that you don't know 'how' yet, but you need to specify 'what'

Comment: Yes from the question it's not really clear why you use a for loop? If you want the last element just do `a[-1]`. If you really do need that for loop please clarify why.

Comment: We can surely make it more elegant, can you post the list of lists, and the expected output @buras12

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop in your code will assign an element from the list `a` to the `el` variable in `each` loop. Type of `el` is string (`str`) and using `[-1]` on string objects is called [String Manipulation](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python).

If a = ['1', '5', '10']:

```
1. el = '1', el[-1] = '1', el[0] = '1'
2. el = '5', el[-1] = '5', el[0] = '5'
3. el = '10', el[-1] = '0', el[0] = '1'
```

So, you can just use the `el` variable instead of using `[-1]` on it.
And if you want the last element in the list `a`, just use `a[-1]`, no need for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a[-1] as that gives you the last element of the list ('10').
Doing the for loop is wrong, and it gives you a[-1][-1] when you reach the last element of the string, which is '0'. Remember that in python, a string is also treated as a list.

So if x = '10' , x[0] = '1' and x[1] = x[-1] = '0'

Also if you want the output as an integer, you can cast the output as int(a[-1])